# Find all files that have set UID bit on

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, find

I'm trying to find all files with the permission "SUID" and write it to a text file, but when I run the following command, the text file is empty:

```
sudo find / -perm 4000 > suid.txt
```

Is there a problem with my command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
sudo find / -perm -4000 > suid.txt
```

or

```
sudo find / -perm -u+s > suid.txt
```

For example:

```
sudo find / -perm -4000 -exec ls -l {} +
```

Gives this output:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root        30800 May 15  2015 /bin/fusermount
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root        94792 Sep  2  2015 /bin/mount
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root        44168 May  7  2014 /bin/ping
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root        44680 May  7  2014 /bin/ping6
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root        36936 Jan 27  2016 /bin/su
<truncated>
```

The issue with your command is that it is looking for mode bits where set uid bit is set and **nothing else** is set.  Adding a `-` prefix would look for all modes where set uid is set, regardless of other bits.

From `man find`:

> -perm mode
>
> File's  permission  bits are exactly mode (octal or symbolic). 
>   Since an exact match is required, if you want to use this form for
>   symbolic modes, you may have to specify a rather complex mode string. 
>   For example -perm g=w will only match files which have mode 0020 (that
>   is, ones for which group write permission is the only permission set).
>   It is more likely that you will want to use the `/' or`-' forms, for
>   example -perm -g=w, which matches any file with group write
>   permission.
>
> -perm -mode
>
> All  of the permission bits mode are set for the file.  Symbolic
>   modes are accepted in this form, and this is usually the way in which
>   would want to use them.  You must specify `u',`g' or `o' if you use a
>   symbolic mode.